# RequireJS callback dependency for modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We're building web app that uses RequireJS for modular development/dependency management.
We kick things of with the following:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

The web app also uses a third-party applet that is required for communication with a mainframe system.  The applet has a callback function that executes once the api for communicating with it has been initialized, with the api object passed in as a parameter.
e.g.

```
/*
 * This function is invoked automatically after the Reflection session has 
 * completed its initialization. A reference to the JavaScript API is passed
 * in as a parameter.
 */
 function jsapiInitialized( api ) {

    return api;

 }
```

Basically, the above needs to be a dependency for many of the modules within the app.

**How can I make the above function a module dependency, so the api object is available to those modules requiring it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to use asynchronous like `define` method for your API. To do it with require.js you'll need to [create](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) a small plugin. As result you'll have the following files:

**1) myapi.js** (API simulation file)

```
// this is actually simulation of your third party code
setTimeout(function() {
    if(typeof jsapiInitialized === 'function') jsapiInitialized('hello!');
}, 1000);
```

**2) myplugin.js** (plugin which handles your API callback)

```
define(function(){
    return {
        load : function(name, req, onLoad, config){
            window.jsapiInitialized = function(api) {
                onLoad(api);
            };
            require([name]);
        }
    };
});
```

**3) main.js** (to test your plugin)

```
require(['myplugin!myapi'], function(api){
    alert(api);
});
```

(where *"myapi"* can be a path to your real API script)

Comment: We don't have access to any api script (that I'm aware of), we simply add the jsapiInitialized() to the page and the applet calls it, passing in the api parameter.  Is that a problem?

Comment: That's no problem for you. You don't need to modify anything. As you can see `jsapiInitialized` function is created automatically by this piece of code: `window.jsapiInitialized = function(api) {...`. And when it's get called from third party script this function simply pass API via requirejs internals.

Comment: OK, since `jsapiInitialized` is called automatically, is myapi.js needed?  If not, what would `require()` parameters look like in main.js?

Comment: No, you don't need *myapi.js* - it is just simulation of your case. This is actually your "third party script". I've make these local files to test my answer. Your require parameters should look like: `require(['myplugin!http://example.com/api.js'])` (you can use relative path also)

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought but wasn't sure.  I just need to find the location of the api.js.  That should be easy...  Thank you again for your help!  BTW, is this typically what plugins are used for, outside dependencies?

Comment: Plugins for RequireJS can be used to load different types of resources. F.e. you can handle localization with it, or some Google APIs. Here's the link with some plugins for RequireJS: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins

Comment: here is the problem, the javascript object is built within the Java code, which also calls the `jsapiInitialized()` function.  Without an actual .js file, is it possible to use this approach to solve the original problem?

Comment: Not enough details about how this file is attached and what's inside it. But I think you can just override `jsapiInitialized` global function by your `myplugin.js`.

Comment: There is no file, the Java applet code builds the api object and then calls `jsapiInitialized()` function, once its ready for use.  How should I override the function?

Comment: If there's no file for that function, where it's located? In HTML code? Try to add `alert(1)` inside `myplugin.js` before line `onLoad(API)`. Does it even show? Maybe you require your API after applet initialized? If so you can save original API to global variable and update `myplugin.js` to fetch it from there. One more question - don't you have your applet wrapped in `<iframe>/<frameset>`?

Comment: The code that is responsible for calling `jsapiInitialized` is the applet code.  `jsapiInitialized` is simply called by java code and passed the api object for use.  Its basically saying Applet is initialized/ready.  Adding alert(1) shows the alert...The applet is wrapped within `<object>`.  I'm getting stuck with the fact that there is no external .js file that represents `myapi.js` in your example.  At what point would I store original API to global variable, and how would I fetch it?  Thanks!

Comment: I just declared a global var and placed `function jsapiInitialized(api)` within the global scope (not within any modules) and have it set the global var, this seems to work, but it would still be nice to tie this into requireJS.

Comment: I understand how your applet creates API, but too bad I don't have access to full code, or test case. You need `myapi.js` actually (this file can be empty and used only to enable our custom requirejs plugin - `myplugin`). So this call: `require(['myplugin!myapi'],...` is necessary. Assuming that global variable helps, you can make updates to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/yzUKc/ (It's quiet hard to answer about such things without seeing actual code).

Comment: Yeah, we can't see the applet code either, since its a third-party tool.  I will search for it and see what I can find though.  Thank you for the example, and all your help, much appreciated!